# Focus an element inside a window without activating it

Tags: wpf, focus

I've got a window (which acts as a kind of popup window) with a couple of buttons inside. The popup disappears after some time. However, when the window is activated I don't want it to disappear until it is deactivated. I achieve this by listening to the `Activated` and `Deactivated` events.

The problem arises when I start calling [`Focus()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the elements inside the window. This focuses the element as expected, however, additionally [`IsActive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.isactive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the window seems to change to `true`.

This is not the behavior I am after. Surprisingly, this is also not visible in the UI. The window does not get styled as if it is activated (black shadow).

Can I move the focus in a window, without activating it?

Comment: Why do you want focused element in the first place if you don't want activity? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @manuell Generally, I want to change the focus in case the window does get activated. Visually, I also want to ensure the blinking caret of a  `TextBox` disappears. Through short keys (kind of like alt-tab) I want to cycle through the buttons, which I do visually by focusing them.

Comment: If you have a caret, you have focus, then activity. Can't you create the popup without activity? What's the point to cycle through the buttons if the window in not activated? You should edit question with more details on your User Interface needs.